# Class for textbox first letter to title case

Tags: c#

is there anything wrong in my class? I just want to Uppercase the first letter and lower case the rest.
I got an error message

> cannot convert from void to object

this is my class:

```
class UpperCaseFirstLetter
{
    private string text; 
    public void SetText(Control control)
    {
        text = control.Text;
        text = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(text.ToLower());
    }
```

codes below is where I use the class:

```
newConnection.ConnectionM();
SqlCommand cmd = SqlConnectionOLTP.cn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Insert into CostCategory(CostCategoryName,Description) values (@costcategoryname,@description)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@costcategoryname",Format.SetText(textBoxCostName));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", textBoxCostDescription.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlConnectionOLTP.cn.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Save");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SetText` returns `void` but in `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` you are using it as it returns value. Change it to

```
public string SetText(Control control)
{
    text = control.Text;
    text = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(text.ToLower());
    return text;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

there are few things to consider here:

- first, you don't need class for that task, method would suffice. Event method is not necessary, you can do it in place
- your class is not returning text nor setting text to control
- you haven't instantiated your class.

To achieve that, you can simply do this

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@costcategoryname",
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(textBoxCostName.Text));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
TextInfo control = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
title = control.ToTitleCase(title);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase(v=vs.110).aspx